# python subprocess hang on reading a pipe

Tags: python

I have this but the subprocess reading from pipe at the end hangs:

```
$cat waitforinput.sh
#!/bin/sh


while read line
do
echo $line
done                    


>>> p1 = subprocess.Popen(["/home/abc/waitforinput.sh", "-v"], shell=True, executable=None,stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> 
>>> 
>>> p1.stdin.write('This is a good idea\n')
>>> p1.stdin.write('This is a good idea\n')
>>> p1.stdin.write('This is a good idea\n')
>>> p1.stdin.write('This is a good idea\n')
>>> p1.stdin.write('This is a good idea\n')
>>> 
>>> 
>>> p1.stdin.flush()
>>> 
>>> for i in p1.stdout:
...     print i 
...
```

What should I do so that it does not hang?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of flush(), call `p1.stdin.close()`.

```
...
p1.stdin.write('This is good idea\n')
p1.stdin.write('This is good idea\n')

p1.stdin.close()

for i in p1.stdout:
    print i
```

**UPDATE**

Replace `stdout-iteration` with **while-loop with stdout.readline()**

Refer python manpage `-u` part:

> Force  stdin,  stdout  and  stderr to be totally unbuffered.  On
>   systems where it matters, also put stdin, stdout and  stderr  in
>   binary  mode.   Note  that there is internal buffering in xread‐
>   lines(), readlines() and file-object  iterators  ("for  line  in
>   sys.stdin")  which  is  not  influenced by this option.  To work
>   around this, you will want to use "sys.stdin.readline()"  inside
>   a "while 1:" loop.

```
p1.stdin.flush()

while True:
    line = p1.stdout.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    print line
```

You will get output, but without `close()`, the script will not end. Anyway you should use `close()`.

Comment: That worked. Thanks. Two more questions: 1. Why did `flush()` not work ? 2. And why did "-v" argument seemed to have no effect?

Comment: @abc, Your shell script does not handle any command line argument.

Comment: @abc, As far as I know, buffer is not flushed until pipe size met. (Check pipe size in `ulimit -a`)

Comment: From pydoc for subprocess: " On UNIX, with shell=True: If args is a string, it specifies the command string to execute through the shell.  If args is a sequence, the first item specifies the command string, and any additional items will be treated as additional shell arguments."  So -v should be treated as a shell argument.

Comment: @abc, `-v` is not interpreted by shell. That should be handled by script. Something like `*`, `$HOSTNAME`, .. are substituted by shell.

Comment: @abc, The documentation is right. I think you interpret `treated as additional shell arguments` differently.

Comment: You are right. I indeed interpreted it incorrectly. It should have been written as "treated as additional command line or command string arguments"

Comment: Of course a much simpler solution is to just call `communicate`. If you're just going to do all your writing, then close stdin, then do all your reading, it already does that for you. If you're trying to do something more complicated than `communicate` can do, you will need to do all the stuff it does with background threads, _plus_ all the stuff it doesn't do with managing the pipe buffers.

Comment: @abarnert `Popen.communicate()` is very helpful indeed. I need to make it a habit to remember it.

Comment: @abarnert Quick question though. When I did a `p1.communicate("This is a good idea\n")` my process was killed. Why did that happen?

Comment: You can only call `communicate` _once_. You gather all your input, send it all at once, and get back the results all at once as a big string, and then the child process is done. When you need to stream data a little bit a time, this doesn't work. But in your case, your original problem is that you don't have enough data to stream it a little bit at a time anyway, so there's no real downside to rewriting around `communicate`.

Comment: @abarnert Thanks abarnert for the clarification! Your help to help me learn is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that waitforinput.sh is buffering its output. falsetru's solution works because the close causes the script to exit and that flushes its output buffers. This is the normal way to handle pipelined commands.

If you want the output interactively, you can use the pty module or pexpect to trick the script into thinking that it is writing to a terminal. Then, its output will only be line buffered.